# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "shopify-buy". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

When I am trying to use **import Client from "shopify-buy";** in myscripts.js file getting this error
**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "shopify-buy". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Already included 
also did **npm install shopify-buy**

When I am trying to use **import Client from "shopify-buy";** in myscripts.js file getting this error
**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "shopify-buy". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

Already included 
also did **npm install shopify-buy**

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet for more reference ? 
like how are you importing the "client".

Comment: **package.json**
{
  "dependencies": {
    "shopify-buy": "^2.18.0"
  }
}

**myscript.js**
import Client from "shopify-buy";
 

**index.html** <script type="module" src="./myscripts.js"></script>